# SOAP & iOS: Any guidance?

Tags: ios, soap, service, wsdl

I am trying to use WSDL and SOAP with my iOS application. And I am desperate. Seems the 2 code generators, Sudz.com and WSDL2OBJC are not suitable. One has TONS of memory leaks, and the other one has other minor problems.

I want 3 things:
1) A test WSDL file for learning, and a test service wrapped around it. I couldn't find any, no matter how hard I tried.
2) A good tutorial on the matter. After a lot of searching, I still haven't found any good one. 
3) A little more guidance on what to do, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Christos: I wrote several WSDL2Objc tutorials here http://brismith66.blogspot.com/search/label/iPhone%20Development  I use various publicly accessible services for the samples.  I hope my tutorials fall into your "good" category :-)

Regards,
Brian

Comment: I have read that WSDL2ObjC creates tons of memory leaks, therefore I refrained myself from using it... Can you verify if memory leaks are present in this? Have you used it extensively?

Comment: Xcode's "Build and Analyze" doesn't report problems with the generated code, and instruments doesn't report leaks. We have used Wsdl2objc fairly extensively, with relatively complex wsdls, and we've had good results.

Comment: @brismith Does it work smoothly? Or did you have some bad experience to share? Do you recommend it?

Comment: @CarlosRicardo I found it to be an effective tool; I did have to play with it a bit to "figure it out," and my learning experiences prompted me to write the tutorials. Again, we found wsdl2objc to be a great help in the projects for which we used it.

Comment: I must say that tools such as this must be used in an already formed and final web service. If you believe that requirements, names, variables could change in WSDL, it's best to go hardcore plain programming, since you will be able to make changes without too much effort.