# How to construct a body of request for SOAP in iOS

Tags: iphone

**How to construct a body of request for SOAP in  iOS**

I have to construct a request body in SOAP,I can able to get the data using RESTClient on firefox i want to get the same in iOS

Answer (score 0):

[SOAP & iOS: Any guidance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696137/soap-ios-any-guidance)

Check out the above link.

For WSDL there is an online class generator

www.sudz.com

What you all need to do is just post your SOAP client URL on the sudz and you will have sample project downloading option having code to access the methods and properties of that SOAP client.

I think this will help you out.